# SQL Case statement /where clause issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am trying to dynamically modify my where clause by using a declared variable in a case statement above.  Forgive me if there is a simple answer to this that I'm missing, but I'm entirely self taught and still have a lot to learn.  Here's a sample of the syntax.  I am not going to bother with the entire syntax of the statement, just enough that hopefully you will understand what I'm trying to do.

```
declare @myvar1 double
declare @myvar2 double

SELECT
q1.host_po_nbr,
q1.etd,
CASE
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 11
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 2 Then 12
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 3 Then 13
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 4 Then 14
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 5 Then 15
END @myvar1,
CASE
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 5
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 2 Then 6
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 3 Then 7
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 4 Then 8
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 5 Then 9
END @myvar2,
FROM q1
WHERE q1.etd BETWEEN today - @myvar1 AND today - @myvar2
```

Comment: it's not real clear what you're wanting to do here..

Comment: The case statement makes no sense at all, only the first =1 will be valid. Second, you can't use variables like this, you could easily solve this with a sub query

Comment: maybe you're trying to set the value of `@myvar1` and `@myvar2` but you need to do that before your select query.. `Set @myvar1 = CASE` and   `Set @myvar2 = CASE` then `Select where q1.etd BETWEEN today - @myvar1 AND today - @myvar2`

Comment: I'm with @JamieD77 here, try to formulate what you're attempting to do in words before including your current snippet. When you have a problem, the snippet is usually wrong making it hard to extrapolate a meaning from it.

Comment: My apologies.  I got so wrapped up in getting this in there that I mis-typed it in my haste.  I will try and explain it as you suggested in the comment.  I appreciate everyone's quick responses to this so far.  Thank you all.

Basically I have a query that will run every morning via a scheduling system.  The Where criteria specifying the amount of days in my between statement will need to adjust based on the day the query is being run.  If it runs on Monday (day 1) then it will need to be between -11 and -5.  If it runs on Tuesday (day 2) then it will need to be between -12 and -6 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're only using variables to try and reference the calculation in the `SELECT` clause from your `WHERE` clause.  You can't reference aliases from the `SELECT` in your `WHERE` clause (at least not in most SQL systems).  The reason is that The `WHERE` clause is evaluated *before* the select, so those aliases do not exist at the time the `WHERE` clause is being evaluated.  You can use a subquery, however:

```
SELECT * FFROM
   (SELECT
    q1.host_po_nbr,
    q1.etd,
    CASE
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 11
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 12
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 13
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 14
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 15
    END myvar1,
    CASE
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 5
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 6
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 7
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 8
    WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 9
    END myvar2,
    FROM q1
    ) q
    WHERE etd BETWEEN today - myvar1 AND today - myvar2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT

q1.host_po_nbr,
q1.etd,
CASE
WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 11
WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 12
WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 13
WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 14
WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 15
END myvar1,
CASE
WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 5
WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 6
WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 7
WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 8
WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 Then 9
END myvar2,

FROM q1
HAVING q1.etd BETWEEN today - myvar1 AND today - myvar2
```

This, however, could be inefficient. If this does not solve your problem, post more details, in particular, your table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) and a good description of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Most SQL systems don't let you reference SELECT aliases from the WHERE clause.  SQL Server is one of them.

Comment: For some reason I thought this was tagged MySQL - MySQL allows that syntax.

Comment: Not accouring to the [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Comment: Worked for me in 5.5:`mysql> create table t1 (n int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 values (1),(2);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select n + 1 as foo,n from t1 having foo = 3;
+------+------+
| foo  | n    |
+------+------+
|    3 |    2 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
`

Comment: The documentation also restricts WHERE but not HAVING.